# How to create an if else statement for length units with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

My goal is to create a true mathematical statement with length units. The only part I am having trouble with, is the if else part of the Javascript. What should I change, so that my if else statement for length units works? This is what I have done so far:

```js
var operators = ['+', '-'];
var e = ['km', 'm'];

function F1() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  rnum1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  rnum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  num1.innerHTML = rnum1;
  num2.innerHTML = rnum2;
  oper = document.getElementById("operator");
  op = operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  oper.innerHTML = op;
  eht = document.getElementById("e1");
  eht2 = document.getElementById("e2");
  eh = e[Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length)];
  eh2 = e[Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length)];
  eht.innerHTML = eh;
  eht2.innerHTML = eh2;
  answer = document.getElementById("answer");

  if (eh = 'km') {
    if (eh2 = 'm') {
      answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2);
    } else {
      if (eh = 'm') {
        if (eh2 = 'km') {
          answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2 * 1000);
        } else {
          if (eh = 'km') {
            if (eh2 = 'km') {
              answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2 * 1000);
            } else {
              answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2)
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<p> <label id="num1"> </label> <label id="e1"> </label>
  <label id="operator"> </label>
  <label id="num2"> </label> <label id="e2"> </label> =
  <label id="answer">m </label> </p>
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
```

Comment: `=` assigns a value ... `==` or `===` tests for equality ... so `if(eh = 'km')` assigns the value `km` to `eh` then the expression evaluates as "truthy", so that code is always executed

Comment: Use `else if` rather than `else { if` so it doesn't add an indentation level.

Comment: `if (eh == 'm')` will never be true because it's nested inside `if (eh == 'km')`.

Comment: You should declare your variables to make them local to the function.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval()` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised for what I was trying to create i didn’t needed to add an `else` statement. So I replaced all `if else` statements with the code below and then it worked:

```
if (eh === 'km') 
    {if (eh2 === 'm') 
    {answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2);}}

if (eh === 'm') 
    {if (eh2 === 'km') 
    {answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2 * 1000);}}

if (eh === 'km') 
    {if (eh2 === 'km') 
    {answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2 * 1000);}}

if (eh === 'm') 
    {if (eh2 === 'm') 
    {answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I understood the problem better but I updated your IF-ELSE logic as per Jaromanda X's observation.

`=` is only for assigning values and should not be used to check equality.
Instead, you should use either `==` or `===` when trying to evaluate the equality of multiple values.

For more information on this concept, please refer to [MDN Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Below is an updated version of your code that compiles and runs but again, I'm not sure what exactly the expected result is so I will let you determine if it is working as expected now or not.

```html
<script>
    var operators = ['+', '-'];
    var e = ['km', 'm'];

    function F1() {
        num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
        num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
        rnum1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        rnum2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        num1.innerHTML = rnum1;
        num2.innerHTML = rnum2;
        oper = document.getElementById("operator");
        op = operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
        oper.innerHTML = op;
        eht = document.getElementById("e1");
        eht2 = document.getElementById("e2");
        eh = e[Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length)];
        eh2 = e[Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length)];
        eht.innerHTML = eh;
        eht2.innerHTML = eh2;
        answer = document.getElementById("answer");

        if (eh === 'km') {
            if (eh2 === 'm') {
                answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2);
            }

            else {
                if (eh === 'm') {
                    if (eh2 === 'km') {
                        answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2 * 1000);
                    }

                    else {
                        if (eh === 'km') {
                            if (eh2 === 'km') {
                                answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 * 1000 + op + rnum2 * 1000);
                            }
                            else {
                                answer.innerHTML = eval(rnum1 + op + rnum2)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<p>
    <label id="num1"> </label> <label id="e1"> </label>

    <label id="operator"> </label>

    <label id="num2"> </label> <label id="e2"> </label>

    = <label id="answer">m </label>
</p>
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
```

Comment: the expected result should be a random true length equation for exemple: 1km + 2km = 3000m or 1m + 1km = 1001m (m stands for meter and km stands for kilometer)